# On a <div> element how to prioritize the href and onClick calls?

Tags: javascript, extjs, onclick, dom-events

I have a code where on clicking on a file name, the file is downloaded (making backend call) and a store needs to be reloaded to track this file download event (by a backend call again).

```
'<div id ="myId"> <a  onClick="reloadStore()" href="/downloadFile/' + fileId + '.pdf" > MyFileName</a></div>'

reloadStore = function(){
//do something
}
```

I want the file download call to be made before the onClick call is made. I even tried to write the code as follows but I still get the same result.

```
'<div id ="myId"> <a  href="/downloadFile/' + fileId + '.pdf" > MyFileName</a></div>'

Ext.get('myId').on('click', function(eventObj, elRef) {
                        //do something 
                    });
```

How can the href call precede the onClick call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do a simple delay:

```
Ext.get('myId').on('click', function() {
}, null, { delay: 1 });
```

This will put the handler into an asynchronous setTimeout which will then execute after the current javascript thread is executed.